# How to use $ positional operator in MongoDB C# driver version 2

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to update a field of one element from array sub document of a document.

MongoDB have the $ positional operator to do this. But in MongoDB C# driver version 2 it seems that there is no support for this operator.

How can I achieve this?

**Documents:**

```
{ "_id" : 1, "grades" : [ 80, 85, 90 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "grades" : [ 88, 90, 92 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "grades" : [ 85, 100, 90 ] }
```

**Expected query:**

```
db.students.update(
     { _id: 1, grades: 80 },
     { $set: { "grades.$" : 82 } }
   )
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
var builder = Builders<Student>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq(student=> student.Id, 1) & builder.ElemMatch(student => student.Grades, x => x == 80);

var builder = Builders<Student>.Update;
var update = builder.Set(student => student.Grades[-1], 82);

var result = collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a very late answer, but if anyone else comes across this I tried s7vr's answer with the -1 index and got an exception that pointed to Mongo's [FirstMatchingElement](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.16/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_Linq_MongoEnumerable_FirstMatchingElement__1.htm) method, and that solved my problem.

So it would be the same `filter` as in that answer, but replacing `update` with something like

```
var update = Builders<Student>.Update.Set(student => student.Grades.FirstMatchingElement(), 82);
```