# Expression tree is not supported on UpdateOneAsync

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

On calling UpdateOneAsync, with this wrapper:

```
    public async Task<UpdateResult> UpdateDocument<T>(
        string sCollectionName, 
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, 
        UpdateDefinition<T> update,
        bool bUpsert,
        System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken
        )
    {
        IMongoDatabase db = _mongoClient.GetDatabase(_optionsMonitor.CurrentValue.databasename);

        IMongoCollection<T> collection = db.GetCollection<T>(sCollectionName);

        return await collection.UpdateOneAsync<T>(filter, update, new UpdateOptions() { IsUpsert = bUpsert }, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Like so:

```
private async Task<Models.Errors> UpdateDbOnSyncServerToBoardUpdate(
        CancellationToken cancel,
        MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument bsonDocConfigurationToUpdate,
        DateTime dtUpdated,
        string sId,
        int iObjectId,
        string sAppName,
        string sModelName
        )
    {
        MongoDB.Driver.UpdateResult updateResult = null;
        Models.Errors errors = null;

        try
        {
            updateResult = await _db.UpdateDocument<Models.Database.NodeBoardModel>(
                Constants.NodeBoardCollectionName,
                node => node.Id == sId && 
                node.RemoteBoard.apps.SingleOrDefault(
                    app => app.appname == sAppName).objects.
                    SingleOrDefault(model => model.name == sModelName).config_docs.
                    Any(config => config.config_id == iObjectId),
                MongoDB.Driver.Builders<Models.Database.NodeBoardModel>.Update.
                Set(
                    node => node.RemoteBoard.apps[-1].objects[-1].config_docs[-1].config_doc, bsonDocConfigurationToUpdate).
                Set(
                    node => node.RemoteBoard.apps[-1].objects[-1].config_docs[-1].config_dt, dtUpdated),
                false,
                cancel
                );
```

I receive a NotSupportedException:

> The expression tree is not supported: {document}{RemoteBoard}{apps}.SingleOrDefault(app => (app.appname == "eACM")).objects.SingleOrDefault(model => (model.name == "tag")).config_docs

I sense I am using a LINQ keyword the wrong way or in a way that's not supported by MongoDb but it's hard to tell exactly where the problem lies.

I can't make anything of the stack trace:

> at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.EmbeddedPipeline.EmbeddedPipelineBinder.BindNonMethodCall(Expression node)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.BindPipeline(Expression node)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.BindMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.EmbeddedPipeline.EmbeddedPipelineBinder.Bind(Expression node, IBindingContext parent)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.SerializationBinder.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.SerializationBinder.Visit(Expression node)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.SerializationBinder.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.SerializationBinder.Visit(Expression node)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate[TDocument](Expression`1 predicate, IBsonSerializer`1 parameterSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.ConvertWriteModelToWriteRequest(WriteModel`1 model, Int32 index)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIterator[TSource,TResult](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`3 selector)+MoveNext()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.BulkMixedWriteOperation..ctor(CollectionNamespace collectionNamespace, IEnumerable`1 requests, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.CreateBulkWriteOperation(IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWriteAsync(IClientSessionHandle session, IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSessionAsync[TResult](Func`2 funcAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.UpdateOneAsync(FilterDefinition`1 filter, UpdateDefinition`1 update, UpdateOptions options, Func`3 bulkWriteAsync)
>      at WebApplication.Services.ConcreteDatabase.UpdateDocument[T](String sCollectionName, Expression`1 filter, UpdateDefinition`1 update, Boolean bUpsert, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\GIT\app-manager\APIMM\ServerLevelConfiguration\WebApplication\Services\ConcreteDatabase.cs:line 131
>      at WebApplication.Services.SyncBoardDatabaseBackgroundService.UpdateDbOnSyncServerToBoardUpdate(CancellationToken cancel, BsonDocument bsonDocConfigurationToUpdate, DateTime dtUpdated, String sId, Int32 iObjectId, String sAppName, String sModelName) in C:\GIT\app-manager\APIMM\ServerLevelConfiguration\WebApplication\Services\SyncBoardDatabaseBackgroundService.cs:line 353

Model classes:

```
public class NodeBoardModel
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    public NodeBoardRemoteModel RemoteBoard { get; set; }
}

public class NodeBoardRemoteModel
{
    [BsonElement]
    public List<NodeBoardAppModel> apps { get; set; }
}

public class NodeBoardAppModel
{
    [BsonElement]
    public string appname { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    public List<NodeBoardObjectModel> objects { get; set; }
}

public class NodeBoardObjectModel
{
    [BsonElement]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    public List<NodeBoardObjectConfigurationModel> config_docs { get; set; }
}

public class NodeBoardObjectConfigurationModel
{
    [BsonElement]
    public BsonDocument config_doc { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    public DateTime config_dt { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    public int config_id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem starts when you're trying to build your `Update` statement. As you probably know `-1` passed as an index will be [translated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42396877/how-to-use-positional-operator-in-mongodb-c-sharp-driver-version-2) to the [$ positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/). The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#nested-arrays) says that

> The positional $ operator **cannot** be used for queries which traverse more than one array, such as queries that traverse arrays nested within other arrays, because the replacement for the $ placeholder is a single value

Additionally you're trying to build your filtering condition using `SingleOrDefault` and .NET MongoDB driver is not able to translate that into any MongoDB query syntax operator.

How to fix that ?

Instead of using the positional operator you can try using the [positional filtered operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) syntax.

```
var filter = Builders<NodeBoardModel>.Filter.Eq(f => f.Id, sId);
var update = Builders<NodeBoardModel>.Update.Set("RemoteBoard.apps.$[app].objects.$[object].config_docs.$[configdoc].config_dt", dtUpdated);

var arrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition>();
ArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument> appFilter = new BsonDocument("app.appname", new BsonDocument("$eq", sAppName));
ArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument> objectFilter = new BsonDocument("object.name", new BsonDocument("$eq", sModelName));
ArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument> configDocFilter = new BsonDocument("configdoc.config_id", new BsonDocument("$eq", iObjectId));

arrayFilters.AddRange(new[] { appFilter, objectFilter, configDocFilter });

var updateOptions = new UpdateOptions { ArrayFilters = arrayFilters };

var res = Col.UpdateOne(filter, update, updateOptions);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been fighting this all morning.