# Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path Mongo

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I'm having a bug in `mongoDb` when I update a list that is inside another array

First code down is method responsible for change

First image representation of my json file, I need to change `dependentBenefits`

> ERROR RETURN: Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path
>   'dependents.$.dependents Benefits.$.type.required

[image]

```
   public string UpdateBenefits(string ownerId, string benefitsId, Benefits DocumentsIn)
        {

            _employee.FindOneAndUpdate(
               c => c.ownerId == ownerId && c.dependents.Any(s => s.Id == benefitsId),
               Builders<Employee>.Update.Set(c => c.dependents.ElementAt(-1).dependentsBenefits.ElementAt(-1), DocumentsIn));


            return benefitsId;

        }
```

Comment: You can take a look at this answer - it's the same reason, and the same solution should work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55597781/expression-tree-is-not-supported-on-updateoneasync/55598918#55598918

Comment: I used the same example but in my scenario: "dependents. $ [Dependent] .dependentsBenefits. $ [Benefits]"  I  get     ErrorMessage = "No array filter found for identifier 'dependent' in path 'dependents.$[dependent].dependentsBenefits.$[benefits]'"

Comment: Positional `$` cannot be used multiple times within a statement and can only be used **once**. The modern solution is [positional filtered `$[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/), but you should also strongly consider **not nesting arrays** as such structures are basically not possible to atomically update until recent versions and are still notoriously difficult to query.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I did not understand one of both examples. It is not the same as the errors are different. If you knew, you could give me an example ?