# MongoDb - not adding array object at proper place instead its adding it to root

Tags: java, mongodb

I have only one collection in my Mongodb and that is as follows

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "timestamp": 1626753855,
            "date": "2021-07-20T04:04:15.000+00:00"
        },
        "metadata": [
            {
                "country": "Canada",
                "authors": [
                    {
                        "author": "Test Author",
                        "Books": [
                            {
                                "name": "Sample Book",
                                "code": "JCAR"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The method I am using is as follows

```
    private void updateAuthorsMetadata(AuthorMetadata authorMetadata) {
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = mDatabase.getCollection(authorMetadataCollection);

        Bson eqFilter = eq("metadata.country", "Canada");
        FindIterable<Document> itrDoc = collection.find(eqFilter);
        if (itrDoc.first() == null) {
            Document document = new Document();
            document.append("metadata",
                    Arrays.asList(new Document("country", authorMetadata.getCountry()).append("authors",
                            Arrays.asList(new Document("author", authorMetadata.getAuthorName()).append("Books",
                                    Arrays.asList(new Document("name", authorMetadata.getBookName()).append("code",
                                            authorMetadata.getBookCode())))))));

            collection.insertOne(document);
        } else {
            Bson andFilter = and(eq("metadata.country", "Canada"),
                    eq("metadata.authors.author", "John Doe"));
                    
            FindIterable<Document> itrAndDoc = collection.find(docFilter);

            if (itrAndDoc.first() == null) {
                Document doc = new Document("author", "John Doe).append("Books",
                        Arrays.asList(new Document("name", "Some Book").append("code",
                                "SBD4")));
                Bson update = push("metadata[].authors", doc);

                UpdateResult result = collection.updateOne(eqFilter, update);
            } 
        }
}
```

The issue I am facing is that when I update collection at

> else block

then it is adding the document to the root instead of adding it to the authors array, as shown in the image below.

[image]

How I can update it at the proper location i.e. adding to "authors" array? I am using Java driver v-3.12.7.

Comment: shouldn't it be `if (itrAndDoc.first() != null)`?

Comment: No, as I am adding a new author to the authors array. if (itrAndDoc.first() != null) means there is already an Author present in same country with same name. I will add this condition later after I atleast add new author.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured it out. Anyone out there struggling with same issue can refer to this method. [The issue was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55670273/too-many-positional-i-e-elements-found-in-path-mongo) positional operators, [some forums says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577123/updating-a-nested-array-with-mongodb) that multiple positional operators can't be used below v 3.x.x but I am using 3.12.x and still had this issue. I think the way I am doing is not best/optimal but it works and if anyone direct me to the right direction then it would be great.

```
private void updateAuthorMetadata(AuthorMetadata authorMetadata) {
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = mDatabase.getCollection(authorMetadataCollection);

            Bson bsonEqFilter = eq("metadata.country", authorMetadata.getCountry());
            FindIterable<Document> itrDoc = collection.find(bsonEqFilter);

            Document found = itrDoc.first();
            if (found == null) {
                Document document = new Document();
                document.append("metadata",
                        Arrays.asList(new Document("country", authorMetadata.getCountry()).append("authors",
                                Arrays.asList(new Document("author", authorMetadata.getAuthor()).append("books",
                                        Arrays.asList(new Document("name", authorMetadata.getBookName())
                                                .append("code", authorMetadata.getBookCode())))))));

                collection.insertOne(document);
            } else {
                Bson bsonAndFilter = and(eq("metadata.country", authorMetadata.getCountry()),
                        eq("metadata.authors.author", authorMetadata.getAuthor()));

                FindIterable<Document> itrAndDoc = collection.find(bsonAndFilter);

                if (itrAndDoc.first() == null) {
                    Document document = new Document("author", authorMetadata.getAuthor()).append("Books",
                            Arrays.asList(new Document("name", authorMetadata.getBookName()).append("code",
                                    authorMetadata.getBookCode())));

                    Bson update = push("metadata.$.authors", document);

                    UpdateResult result = collection.updateOne(bsonEqFilter, update);

                } else {
                    Bson bsonMoreAndFilter = and(eq("metadata.country", authorMetadata.getCountry()),
                            eq("metadata.authors.author", authorMetadata.getAuthor()),
                            eq("metadata.authors.books.code", authorMetadata.getBookCode()));

                    FindIterable<Document> itrMoreAndDoc = collection.find(bsonMoreAndFilter);

                    if (itrMoreAndDoc.first() == null) {
                        Document docBooks = new Document("name", authorMetadata.getBookName()).append("code",
                                authorMetadata.getBookCode());

                        Bson update = push("metadata.0.authors.$.books", docBooks);

                        UpdateResult result = collection.updateOne(bsonAndFilter, update);
                    }
                }
            }
}
```