# Insert element into a 3-level deep nested array in MongoDB (C# driver)

Tags: c#, mongodb, insert, nested, mongodb-.net-driver

I have this:

```
{  
   "_id":"2900f1e8-48fa-418b-8e4d-73a6592e5d41",

   "CollectionRequirement":[  
      {  
         "_id":"a6af03b1-8bb3-4cb2-b307-b8831e61ef7d",
         "RequirementName":"CENTCOM14CR-000000000024243T0500089",
         "RequestorID":"IMINT ORG 1",

         "Task":[  
            {  
               "_id":"705284be-492e-4744-8361-f977b81404e9",
               "TaskPriority":"1",

               "CollectionConstraint":[  
                  {  
                     "_id":"99ec8961-647e-45db-98c3-04a91866143e",
                     "SensorID":"ASARS-2A",
                     "SensorMode":"21"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "_id":"af8c7911-0aa3-4ce2-b399-7a997ecde38a",
               "TaskPriority":"2",

               "CollectionConstraint":[  
                  {  
                     "_id":"10ec8961-647e-45db-98c3-04a918661445",
                     "SensorID":"ASARS-2A",
                     "SensorMode":"25"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to add a new **CollectionConstraint** under **Task** where **"TaskPriority == 1"** using the C# driver. Is there a way to do this?

I saw some example code from other posts but those examples works only for a 2-level nested array. See this post for example: [Insert element into nested array in Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731634/insert-element-into-nested-array-in-mongodb)

Comment: Well, since I don't see any answer and I found something that might be useful (not exactly what I need), I'll just post it here anyway just in case people need it.

https://pgraces.wordpress.com/2015/04/13/deeply-nested-sub-documents-with-mongodb-mongoose/