# How to access deeply nested array with MongoDB (ASP.NET Core 2.2)

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, mongodb, ienumerable

I'm designing an inventory management system with MongoDB. I have the following database structure:

```
inventory
└─storage_slots
└─storage_locations
...etc...
```

Every time a new `Slot` is added, a tree representing the slot's location in the hierarchy is added to the `storage_locations` collection to represent its location (according to location, room, section, shelf). So far I have managed to successfully add a new item where none of the location fields are already used: (The slot is also added to the `storage_slots` collection)

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c57169f0863d665c7f13d27"),
"CreatedUtc" : {
    "$date" : 1549211298017
},
"UpdatedUtc" : {
    "$date" : 1549211298017
},
"Description" : null,
"Address" : null,
"StorageRooms" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c57169f0863d665c7f13d28"),
        "CreatedUtc" : {
            "$date" : 1549211297719
        },
        "UpdatedUtc" : {
            "$date" : 1549211297719
        },
        "Description" : null,
        "StorageSections" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5c57169f0863d665c7f13d29"),
                "CreatedUtc" : {
                    "$date" : 1549211297719
                },
                "UpdatedUtc" : {
                    "$date" : 1549211297719
                },
                "Description" : null,
                "StorageShelves" : [
                    {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5c57169f0863d665c7f13d2a"),
                        "CreatedUtc" : {
                            "$date" : 1549211297719
                        },
                        "UpdatedUtc" : {
                            "$date" : 1549211297719
                        },
                        "Description" : null,
                        "StorageSlotIds" : [
                            ObjectId("5c57169f0863d665c7f13d26")
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

To be clear, `storage_locations` is the above hierarchy while `storage_slots` is just a collection of slots.

However, if the fields are already present in the hierarchy, the following code is run: (I took insipration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30737016/9431636) post)

```
var filter = Builders<StorageLocation>.Filter.And(
            Builders<StorageLocation>.Filter.Where(location => location.Id == id),
            Builders<StorageLocation>.Filter.Eq("StorageRooms.Id", roomId),
            Builders<StorageLocation>.Filter.Eq("StorageRooms.$.StorageSections.Id", sectionId),
            Builders<StorageLocation>.Filter.Eq("StorageRooms.$.StorageSections.$.StorageShelves.Id", shelfId));
        var update =
            Builders<StorageLocation>.Update.Push("StorageRooms.$.StorageSections.$.StorageShelves.$.StorageSlotIds",
                storageSlotIds);
        return await UpdateAsync(filter, update, cancellationToken);
```

Also, if only some of them are defined then I do a mix of both that I decided not to show here because they are built on the same principles and would not contribute to the question.

## The problem

Whenever the code directly above is run. I get the following error:

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId[]' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId'.

MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.SerializerBase<TValue>.MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializer.Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, object value)

//annoying scrollbar
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
return await UpdateAsync(filter, update, cancellationToken);
```

The method is:

```
public Task<UpdateResult> UpdateAsync(FilterDefinition<T> filter, UpdateDefinition<T> updateDefinition,
        string database, string collection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _mongoContext.MongoClient.GetDatabase(database).GetCollection<T>(collection)
            .UpdateOneAsync(filter, updateDefinition.Set(o => o.UpdatedUtc, DateTime.UtcNow),
                cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    }
```

## Extra stuff

Here are some more relevant classes for the question:

```
public class StorageLocation : Dbo
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<StorageRoom> StorageRooms { get; set; }
}
public class StorageRoom : Dbo
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<StorageSection> StorageSections { get; set; }
}
public class StorageSection : Dbo
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<StorageShelf> StorageShelves { get; set; }
}
public class StorageShelf : Dbo
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ObjectId> StorageSlotIds { get; set; }
}
public class StorageSlot : Dbo
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ObjectId LocationId { get; set; }
    public ObjectId RoomId { get; set; }
    public ObjectId SectionId { get; set; }
    public ObjectId ShelfId { get; set; }

    ...etc...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because [$ positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#nested-arrays) can be used only once while in your case there are multiple levels of nested arrays. From the docs:

> The positional $ operator cannot be used for queries which traverse more than one array, such as queries that traverse arrays nested within other arrays, because the replacement for the $ placeholder is a single value

To fix that you can use [filtered positional](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) operator which was introduced in MongoDB 3.6. It allows you to specify multiple placeholders in your update path and then you can use `arrayFilters` to define conditions for those placeholders.

```
var filter = Builders<StorageLocation>.Filter.And(
   Builders<StorageLocation>.Filter.Where(location => location.Id == id),
   Builders<StorageLocation>.Filter.Eq("StorageRooms._id", roomId));

var arrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition>();
ArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument> sectionFilter = new BsonDocument("section._id", new BsonDocument("$eq", sectionId));
ArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument> shelfFilter = new BsonDocument("shelf._id", new BsonDocument("$eq", shelfId));
arrayFilters.Add(sectionFilter);
arrayFilters.Add(shelfFilter);

var updateOptions = new UpdateOptions { ArrayFilters = arrayFilters };


var update =
    Builders<StorageLocation>.Update.Push("StorageRooms.$.StorageSections.$[section].StorageShelves.$[shelf].StorageSlotIds",
        storageSlotIds);

await Col.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update, updateOptions);
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much. Now I just need to update the Azure Cosmos DB version to support this somehow...